# view email distribution list members with php

Tags: php, exchange-server

I need to get the list of email addresses that are part of a distribution list on an exchange server. I can connect fine, but the information returned is lacking the subscribers.

```
$hostname = '{rcdn-mail-1.abc123.com:993/imap/ssl}Inbox';
$username = 'user1';
$password = 'password1';

$mbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());


$list = imap_lsub($mbox, "{cmo-maillist}", "*");
if (is_array($list)) {
foreach ($list as $val) {
    print_r($val) . "\n";
}
} else {
echo "imap_list failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
}

imap_close($mbox);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is possible at all? I had to deal with MS-Exchange servers years ago and found out that their support of the standard imap protocol was absolutely buggy and incompatible. So I finally dripped the attempt and used other (sane) mail servers. Just mentioning this to prevent you from investing endless hours too for something that might not be possible at all.

Comment: yea, I'm now looking at a PowerShell option.